# How to check if there is any Zeros in Column Fields using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to check if there is any zeros in Flag1 or Flag2 fields but I am getting the wrong results here when I run the code below.  In this case I know there is one zero in Flag1 field but my count is zero when I run the SQL.   If there is one zero in either field then I am expecting to see the count to be either >=1.  If there is no zero in either field then I expect zero count.  How can I get that?  thanks
here is my code:

```
select count(*) from myTable 
where FLAG1 in(0) and FLAG2 in(0)
and ID = 202
```

Here is an example of what i have:

```
FLAG1    FLAG2
  1         1
  1         1
  1         1
  0         1
```

Comment: If you're still getting `0` with the queries provided below then the record you show with `FLAG1` equal to `0` can't have the `ID` of `202`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) from myTable 
where (FLAG1 = 0 or FLAG2 = 0)
and ID = 202
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `and` use `or` (and don't use `in` unless you provide a list of values or a subquery):

```
select count(*) from myTable 
where (FLAG1=0 or FLAG2=0)
and ID = 202
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be true:

```
 select count(*) from myTable 
    where FLAG1=0 or FLAG2 =0
    and ID = 202
```

Comment: The problem with this is operator precedence. Alawys use parenthese when wmixing and and OR to make sure you get teh corect data.

Comment: No it is not. I ran a query on my database using your structure and using mine  and got roughly 89,000 records returned using yours and 2000 records returned using mine.

Comment: I am 100% sure that there is no difference.

Comment: Then you would be incorrect. I ran the two pieces of code and got different result sets as I knew from many years of writing sql code that I would. Suggest you read up on order of operations.

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz: You must have missed reading: [*MySQL: Operator Precedence*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html)

Comment: @Ravinder: mr this question has been tagged as sql server.

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz: You then still are missing: [*Operator Precedence (Transact-SQL) SQL Server 2012*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx).